# how to color image by taking pixel values from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xampp, heatmap

I want to make a heat map and for that i captured an image from google maps and divided into the grid for example, [image]

Now, i want to color particular grid according to the number of people residing in that grid. For example,
if in grid 7,5 no. of residents are 
7k+ color it with red color.
4k to 7k, color it with orange color.
less that 4k, color it with yellow color.

is there any way i can achieve this.
ps. this is a web application.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a 2d array, like this:

```
data = [ [6323, 9538, 1043, 1023, 4029],
         [3912, 5921, 4893, 9836, 2994],
         ... ];
```

Then just loop through to create a same-sized 2d array with associated colors:

```
colors = [data.length][data[0].length]
for (let row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    let colorRow = []
    for (let col = 0; col < data[0].length; col++) {
        if data[row][col] > 7000 {
            colorRow.append('red');
        } else if data[row][col] > 4000 {
            colorRow.append('orange');
        } else {
            colorRow.append('yellow');
        }
    }
    colors.append(colorRow);
```

Then you can just access the color for any specific cell in the matrix and do whatever you need to with that info:

```
color = colors[0][2] //returns 'red' for 9538
```

Comment: sorry i am kind of newb in programming but i dont see any pixels values where i have to put the color and since all i have is an image ....how exactly will this color the image pixels?

Comment: Ah, your question was ambiguous. I would recommend using P5.js. You can load in the image, and tint individual pixels.

Comment: Thank you.... I was using heatmap.js... But community support for it is not so good..... How is the community support for p5.js??

Comment: I'm not sure, but the documentation and examples on their site are good, and, by design, it's really easy to use.